# How do generics affect possible Parameters/Return types

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

I am practicing for an exam and have the following question:

Consider the following code, and inheritance hierarchies:

```
public Deque<E> theMethod(E arg1, ArrayDeque<E> arg2)
{
return theOtherMethod(arg1, arg2);
}



D<|----E<|----F

Collection<|----------------------Deque<|----------------
    ^                               ^                   |
    |                               |                   |
    |                     |------ArrayDeque             |
    |                     |                             |
    |                     |                             |
    |                     |                             |
AbstractCollection<|------|                             |
                          |                             |
                          ----AbstractList<|----------LinkedList



Considering only the classes shown above:
(a) What types of objects can you supply to theMethod as arguments?
(b) What could the declared parameter types of theOtherMethod be?
(c) What could the declared return type of theOtherMethod be?
```

Hopefully the UML is readable, <| and ^ both indicate inheritance.

My answers are as follows, but I'm not sure they are correct as I don't understand how generics affect the possible params and return types.

```
(a) First param: E and F, second param only ArrayDeque
(b) First param: could be D or E, second param: could be Collection, Deque, ArrayDeque or AbstractCollection
(c) Collection or Deque
```

Comment: Please use different names for `D`, `E`, and `F`. Currently I'm confusing it with type parameters.

Comment: What about `Deque<E>` and `ArrayDeque<E>`?

Comment: I thought that meant they are generics?

Comment: Where did you got that question from? Shouldn't `Deque<E>` be `Deque<Echo>`, or else, the type parameter `E` should be declared for the method.

Comment: I understood the <E> stood for generic, and that is probably not related to the Echo class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a:** theMethod expects an object of type E and an ArrayDeque consisting of the same type E's.

So if you would use a String for E, then the second parameter should be:
`ArrayDeque<String>`. Generics are there to make sure that they are of the same type!

Please note that if your theMethod method is in a generic class, it should be the same type of E that you passed to your class during initialisation:

```
public class Test<E> {
}
```

**b:** The first argument **has to be** E. The second argument can be either: `Deque<E> or ArrayDeque<E>.`

**c:** The returntype of theOtherMethod can be:

```
ArrayDeque, ConcurrentLinkedDeque, LinkedBlockingDeque, LinkedList
```

But in your case, according to your diagram, it can only be:

```
ArrayDeque or LinkedList
```

Because they all implement the Deque class.

If you are having trouble with generics, I would also recommend reading this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I should have said that the classes they return are restriced to the ones in the UML diagram.